# Python LookupError: unknown encoding: cp20936

Tags: python, pip

When I run scripts, it's fine, but when I try to install modules (ie. `pip install python-dateutil`) it would complain about:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp20936
```

Also, when I run python command line, I get this error from every command (including chcp).

I tried reinstalling, same problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please update the post to include the full stack trace that pip throw, and also include python version and OS version.

Comment: It seems an issue of local settings (language encoding)